# How do I display the taxonomy term alongside the post type post title?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I would like to display the taxonomy term of the post type post besides the post type post title, separated by the "in" text string.

There are two issues:

1. only "array" is displayed instead of the term
2. I don't know how to code the "in" text string correctly, between the term and the title (they should be in the same row)

Here is the (wrong) code in question:

`$output .= '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>'; in $output .= '<div>' . wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy = 'itemscategories') . '</div>';`

Embedded in this shortcode:

```
function myprefix_custom_grid_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Parse your shortcode settings with it's defaults
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(

        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'term'           => ''
    ), $atts, 'myprefix_custom_grid' );
$user_id = userpro_get_view_user( get_query_var('up_username') );
    // Extract shortcode atributes
    extract( $atts );

    // Define output var
    $output = '';



    // Define query
    $query_args = array(
    'author'=> $user_id,
        'post_type'      => 'items', // Change this to the type of post you want to show
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    );

    // Query by term if defined
    if ( $term ) {

        $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'ID',
                'terms'    => $term,

            ),
        );

    }

    // Query posts
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    // Add content if we found posts via our query
    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {

        // Open div wrapper around loop
        $output .= '<div>';

        // Loop through posts
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {

            // Sets up post data so you can use functions like get_the_title(), get_permalink(), etc
            $custom_query->the_post();

            // This is the output for your entry so what you want to do for each post.
            $output .= '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>'; in $output .= '<div>' . wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy = 'itemscategories') . '</div>';

        }

        // Close div wrapper around loop
        $output .= '</div>';

        // Restore data
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }

    // Return your shortcode output
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'myprefix_custom_grid', 'myprefix_custom_grid_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The wp_get_post_terms function by default returns an array so if you want to display the first term name you can do something like this:

```
// This is the output for your entry so what you want to do for each post.
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'itemscategories' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $output .= '<div>' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . ' ' . esc_html__( 'Posted in:', 'text_domain' ) . ' ' . esc_html( $terms[0]->name ) . '</div>';
}
```

Or you can instead use the alternative function - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/

```
// This is the output for your entry so what you want to do for each post.
$output .= '<div>' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'itemscategories', 'Posted in: ', ', ' ) . '</div>';
```

This function will display a list of all the terms belonging to the post with links to the term archives. If you want to remove the archive links you can wrap get_the_terms_list inside the strip_tags function.

Comment: Thanks! The first code results in nothing (white space), the second code results in only the titles. I wonder what could be wrong.

Comment: Sorry the first code I had $term[0] instead of $terns (with an "s") I've updated it.

if you look at the source code for get_the_terms_list - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/#source - you see it will return links unless there is an error, you'll want to make sure nothing is funky on your installation causing term links to not work.

Comment: The first code after the correction still results in white space, I wonder why...?

Comment: If you aren't seeing the Posted in: text then WordPress is not able to find any $terms or there is an error try adding var_dump( $terms ) before the if statement to see what is being returned by the database. Also make sure WP_Debug is enabled on your server incase there are any errors.

Comment: debug reports `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/username(edited_by_OP)/public_html/wp-content/themes/total-child-theme-master/functions.php on line 543`

Comment: And var_dump( $terms ); results in "Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in /home/(edited_by_OP)/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5167". Without var dump whitespace is the result, with var dump this is displayed: array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, the posts were not assigned to the taxonomy. Solved!

Comment: But now I would like to show the post title where the post type was posted, instead of the taxonomy, and linking to it. You told me that you don't see any linking you could use for the code and that I should send some hidden field along with the post, but this is already done in the form of gravity forms "embed url".  I wonder how could I retrieve that url via php?

Comment: You were asking about the connection to the post, it's done via the Gravity Forms merge tags, https://docs.gravityforms.com/embed_url/#usage . I just need to find a way to insert such merge tag in the php code above.

Comment: There is also this: https://docs.gravityforms.com/capture-http-referrer-url-form-submissions/

Comment: I am trying to implement this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207313/gravity-forms-merge-tags-in-templates

Comment: I have added the hidden field containing the embed url and have given it a parameter name as shown in the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/NaFDxLm.png  can you tell me how to call this parameter beside the post title? and does it need to be declared, and where?